# htaccess redirect: "example.com/?deletethis" to "example.com"

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I've trying to redirect (with .htaccess file) this:
http://www.example.com/?deletethis
to:
http://example.com

I try this:
    RewriteEngine On

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} deletethis [NC]
RewriteRule . http://example.com/? [R=301,L]
```

But doesn't work, I try this:
    RewriteEngine On

```
Redirect 301 /?deletethis http://example.com
```

But doesn't work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} deletethis [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://example.com/? [R=301,L]
```

Replace `.` with `^`

Comment: Very thanks for your help. Your solution isn't very easy. I worked a few hours on it!!